# Add permissions in Cosmos DB only for specific containers

Tags: azure, permissions, containers, azure-cosmosdb, roles

I'm trying to configure access to a Cosmos DB database that contains multiple containers. In our scenario we want different teams of users to have read and write permissions within specific containers only, if they were to attempt any access to another container then they should be denied.

I've been reading about role based access within Cosmos and it sounds exactly like what we need. So i'm trying to create custom roles for this but I'm getting confused by the different permissions available.

I can't embed images but the link below is the permissions i've found for containers within DocumentDB.

Link to permissions:
[image: Link to permissions]

There's permissions such as Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/write but it sounds like these are for the actual maintenance of containers themselves rather than the data within them. The set below that in the image mention the throughput of the container so that doesn't seem right either.

Previous material i'd seen mentioned that these roles were only available to create from something like PowerShell, however when I saw these within the portal I assumed that may have been outdated, but is that still the case?

Essentially, the setup I want is:

- Role 1 given access to read and write items in container 1 only
- Role 2 given access to read and write items in container 2 only

Also, as another quick side question. Are permissions additive? So can I create this role just for this purpose of accessing that container and then add it onto another more generic role, or would I need to include basic permissions that you would find in something like the Cosmos DB Account Reader Role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions you have are for management operations on Cosmos DB resources. The permissions you are looking for are these which are documented at [Configure role-based access control with Azure Active Directory for your Azure Cosmos DB account](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac)

[image: Comos DB data plane permissions]

First step is to create a role definition for each container. You can use the [Built-in role definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#built-in-role-definitions) such as Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor, or if you want to limit to discreet actions, you can build a custom role definition using az cli, PowerShell or ARM/Bicep.

Once you have your role definitions, you can then [Create role assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#role-assignments) for each container to any service principal within your AAD tenant.

Last step is to [Initialize our SDK with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#initialize-the-sdk-with-azure-ad). This is available for our .NET, Java, Python and JS SDK's. You will need to ensure you are using the correct version of our SDK's so best to upgrade if using older versions. To authenticate via AAD you need to create a client secret credential. The token from which, is what is passed to the Cosmos client when creating a new instance.

Lastly, you will want to use a custom query string when you want to access your data via the Cosmos Data Explorer. You may also want to restrict access to your data to only via AAD. To do this you will need to deploy an ARM template to your account (be sure to do a GET first so you don't accidentally destroy your resources). Then add `"disableLocalAuth": true` to the properties of the databaseAccount resource.